# How to get two same attribute in azure cosmos db

Tags: t-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating a service using cosmos db.I am trying to creating a search query.
Query :

```
SELECT product.Name,product1.Name
FROM catalog
join industry in catalog.Industy 
join category in industry.Category 
join product1 in category.Product 
join Subcategory in category.Subcategory 
join product in Subcategory.Product
 WHERE CONTAINS(product1.Name,'dg')
```

But i can not able to get both product and product list . it give me the error. Name already used.
error:

```
Object creation error, property name 'Name' specified more than once
```

Tree that i am trying to  fetch :

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "industy": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "category": [
          {
            "id": "string",
            "subcategory": [
              {
                "id": "string",
                "product": [
                  {
                    "id": "string",
                    "methodOfPreparation": [
                      {
                        "id": "string",
                      }
                    ],
                    "addons": [
                      {
                        "id": "string"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "product": [
              {
                "id": "string",

                "methodOfPreparation": [
                  {
                    "id": "string"
                  }
                ],
                "addons": [
                  {
                    "id": "string"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

expect Output

```
product[],prodcut1[]
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Use an alias... However, I can't see how you expect to get that json structure with this query.

Comment: my expected output should be return product  array (but product in subcategory and main category)

Comment: but when i use alias it is return data as one array . but for my requirement i need each product as array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the error could be solved if you use alias as @Zohar mentioned in the comment.

```
SELECT product.Name as productName,product1.Name as product1Name
FROM catalog
join industry in catalog.industy 
join category in industry.category 
join product1 in category.product 
join Subcategory in category.subcategory 
join product in Subcategory.product
```

The reason is that every retrieved item is an obj, the format of results is an array consists of many objects. The object can't accept duplicate column names.

[image]

If you want to get the format like `product[],prodcut1[]`,you need to loop the result and assemble by yourself.(For example,use stored procedure)